# Oracle date between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, between, date-arithmetic

I'm looking for rows where Date_Created is greater than 15 minutes ago, back to 4 days ago

This works:

```
where h.Date_Created < (Sysdate - interval '15' minute) and h.Date_Created > (Sysdate - 4)
```

This also works:

```
where h.Date_Created <= (Sysdate - interval '15' minute) and h.Date_Created >= (Sysdate - 4);
```

This returns no rows:

```
where h.Date_Created between (Sysdate - interval '15' minute) and  (Sysdate - 4);
```

Date_Created was defined as type "date".

Why doesn't this "between" statement not work the same as the previous query (it's not an issue of inclusive of the boundaries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sysdate - 4` must be the first

```
where h.Date_Created between (Sysdate - 4) and (Sysdate - interval '15' minute) ;
```

Comment: Duh - so obvious now!  Thanks.